# JavaFX: canvas improperly resized while in the TabsPane

Tags: java, canvas, javafx, tabs

I'm trying to create an app that used JavaFX for GUI. The main windows has a set of tabs, one of which has a canvas that is used for visualization. I have noticed that resizing a canvas is not an easy task and there are lots of the tips and question ralated to this.

I took [this code](http://dlsc.com/2014/04/10/javafx-tip-1-resizable-canvas/) as the example. It works fine, until I try to put it into a TabsPane. When I enlarge the window the image enlarges too, but when I shirk the window, canvas is not shinked! Moreover, the panel on the top of the tab is not shrinked too.

Here is a screenhot of the window that demostrates the issue:

[image: Invalid canvas resize]

Here is the code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * Tip 1: A canvas resizing itself to the size of
 *        the parent pane.
 */
public class Tip1ResizableCanvas extends Application {

    class ResizableCanvas extends Canvas {

        public ResizableCanvas() {
            // Redraw canvas when size changes.
            widthProperty().addListener(evt -> draw());
            heightProperty().addListener(evt -> draw());
        }

        private void draw() {
            double width = getWidth();
            double height = getHeight();

            GraphicsContext gc = getGraphicsContext2D();
            gc.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

            gc.setStroke(Color.RED);
            gc.strokeLine(0, 0, width, height);
            gc.strokeLine(0, height, width, 0);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isResizable() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public double prefWidth(double height) {
            return getWidth();
        }

        @Override
        public double prefHeight(double width) {
            return getHeight();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {


        TabPane tabs = new TabPane();


        Tab tab = new Tab("tab", createNewTaskArea());
        tabs.getTabs().add(tab);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(tabs, 500, 500));
        stage.setTitle("Tip 1: Resizable Canvas");
        stage.show();
    }

    private Pane createNewTaskArea() {
        Label newTaskNameQuery = new Label("Task name:");
        TextField newTaskName = new TextField("Untitled task");
        newTaskNameQuery.setLabelFor(newTaskName);


        GridPane topPane = new GridPane();
        topPane.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        topPane.setHgap(5);
        topPane.setVgap(10);

        topPane.add(newTaskNameQuery, 0, 0);
        topPane.add(newTaskName, 1, 0);

        GridPane.setHalignment(newTaskNameQuery, HPos.RIGHT);

        GridPane.setHgrow(newTaskName, Priority.ALWAYS);


        ResizableCanvas canvas = new ResizableCanvas();

        VBox panel = new VBox();

        // Bind canvas size to stack pane size.
        panel.widthProperty().addListener(observable -> canvas.setWidth(panel.getWidth()));
        panel.heightProperty().addListener(
                observable -> canvas.setHeight(panel.getHeight() - topPane.getHeight())
        );

        panel.getChildren().addAll(topPane, canvas);

        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to make it work properly?

It seems that the TabPane causes the problems, becasue if I remove it and make contents of the tab to be contents of the entire window everything works just like as I expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not work since for the `VBox` to reduce it's size, the `Canvas`'s size would need to be reduced which does not happen, since the `Canvas` size is only decreased when the `VBox` size is reduced...

It's much easier to simply put the `Canvas` inside a resizeable parent, set the appropriate layout parameters for it and resize the `Canvas` based on the size of this parent:

```
class ResizableCanvas extends Canvas {

    public ResizableCanvas() {
        // Redraw canvas when size changes.
        widthProperty().addListener(evt -> draw());
        heightProperty().addListener(evt -> draw());
    }

    private void draw() {
        double width = getWidth();
        double height = getHeight();

        GraphicsContext gc = getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

        gc.setStroke(Color.RED);
        gc.strokeLine(0, 0, width, height);
        gc.strokeLine(0, height, width, 0);
    }

}
```

```
VBox panel = new VBox();

// parent to be resized
Pane pane = new Pane(canvas);

// grow/shrink pane when VBox height is increased/decreased    
VBox.setVgrow(pane, Priority.ALWAYS);

// bind canvas size to parent size
canvas.widthProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty());
canvas.heightProperty().bind(pane.heightProperty());

panel.getChildren().addAll(topPane, pane);
```